# Bootstrap 4 - Modal Video Reload

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap to create a portfolio gallery and upon click, a modal will pop up and the video will play. I will have a series of videos in this gallery and therefore each modal will have a unique #id.

I got the modals up and running and the correct video opens for the designated modal. However, when I close the modal and reopen that modal, a different video plays from another modal. Here's an example below:

`#Modal1` is a video about Sports. `#Modal2`is a video about Weather. When a user clicks on `#Modal1`, the Sports video populates within the modal. When a user clicks on `#Modal2`, the Weather video populates. However, when a user closes `#Modal2` and reopens it, the video about Sports populates. I've tested this by adding other modals and they all re-populate with `#Modal1` after they've been closed.

Also, I'm sure I could condense the JavaScript to function smoother but I am a very green dev. My expertise are in Motion Design, not Dev.. I could use some help!

```js
function stopVideo() {
  var $frame = $('iframe#nofocusvideo');

  // saves the current iframe source
  var vidsrc = $frame.attr('src');

  // sets the source to nothing, stopping the video
  $frame.attr('src', '');

  // sets it back to the correct link so that it reloads immediately on the next window open
  $frame.attr('src', vidsrc);
}

$('#portfolioModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal3').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal4').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal5').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal6').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})
```

```css
.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/**** Portfolio GIF Rollover States ****/

.project-rollover1 {
  background-image: url("../img/portfolio/thumbnails/01-reel.gif");
  background-size: cover;
}

.project-rollover2 {
  background-image: url("../img/portfolio/thumbnails/02-jg-wentworth.gif");
  background-size: cover;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-modal {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-dialog {
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background-image: url("../img/patterns/debut_light.png");
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #333333;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content p {
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content p.item-intro {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content ul.list-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content img {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1051;
  width: 1px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #212529;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1052;
  width: 1px;
  height: 75px;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background-color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
HTML
<!-- Portfolio Grid -->
<section class="p-0 bg-light" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <!-- Project 1 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal1">
          Project1
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption project-rollover1">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Project 2 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal2">
          Project2
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption project-rollover2">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- Portfolio Modals -->

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
              <h2 class="text-uppercase">2018 Reel</h2>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe id="nofocusvideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/250633785" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae,
                nostrum, reiciendis facere nemo!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Date: Mid 2018</li>
                <li>Client: Austin Bonelli</li>
                <li>Category: 2D Animation</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-primary-pink" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                Close Project
                              </button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
              <h2 class="text-uppercase">JG Wentworth</h2>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe id="nofocusvideo" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/202987459" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae,
                nostrum, reiciendis facere nemo!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Date: Mid 2018</li>
                <li>Client: Austin Bonelli</li>
                <li>Category: 2D Animation</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-primary-pink" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                Close Project
                              </button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try unique id for iframes and add a space between id and class attributes of iframe. Not sure if this is the issue, but this should be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, that resolved the issue of the video staying the same within the modal but now when the modal is closed, the video's audio continues to play..

Answer (score 1):

I tried using classes instead of `id`, I noticed you had **two** `iframes` with the same `id` which shouldn't happen, I imagine this was setting the value of the video source to that of the first instance of the `id` the script found; upon changing this, it seems it is actually working as intended. Further clarification might be needed; but I think this is something on the right track.

```js
function stopVideo() {
  var $frame = this.$('iframe.nofocusvideo');

  // saves the current iframe source
  var vidsrc = $frame.attr('src');

  // sets the source to nothing, stopping the video
  $frame.attr('src', '');

  // sets it back to the correct link so that it reloads immediately on the next window open
  $frame.attr('src', vidsrc);
}

$('#portfolioModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $('#portfolioModal1 iframe').attr("src", $("#portfolioModal1 iframe").attr("src"));
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $('#portfolioModal2 iframe').attr("src", $("#portfolioModal2 iframe").attr("src"));
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal3').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal4').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal5').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})

$('#portfolioModal6').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  stopVideo();
})
```

```css
.portfolio-box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/**** Portfolio GIF Rollover States ****/

.project-rollover1 {
  background-image: url("../img/portfolio/thumbnails/01-reel.gif");
  background-size: cover;
}

.project-rollover2 {
  background-image: url("../img/portfolio/thumbnails/02-jg-wentworth.gif");
  background-size: cover;
}

.portfolio-box .portfolio-box-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-box-caption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio-modal {
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-dialog {
  margin: 1rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background-image: url("../img/patterns/debut_light.png");
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content h2 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #333333;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content p {
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content p.item-intro {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content ul.list-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content img {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.portfolio-modal .modal-content button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1051;
  width: 1px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #212529;
}

.portfolio-modal .close-modal .lr .rl {
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  z-index: 1052;
  width: 1px;
  height: 75px;
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background-color: #212529;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
HTML
<!-- Portfolio Grid -->
<section class="p-0 bg-light" id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <!-- Project 1 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal1">
          Project1
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption project-rollover1">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Project 2 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="modal" href="#portfolioModal2">
          Project2
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption project-rollover2">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<!-- Portfolio Modals -->

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
              <h2 class="text-uppercase">2018 Reel</h2>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe id="nofocusvideo" class="nofocusvideo embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/250633785" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae,
                nostrum, reiciendis facere nemo!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Date: Mid 2018</li>
                <li>Client: Austin Bonelli</li>
                <li>Category: 2D Animation</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-primary-pink" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                Close Project
                              </button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
        <div class="lr">
          <div class="rl"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
              <h2 class="text-uppercase">JG Wentworth</h2>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe id="nofocusvideo" class="nofocusvideo2 embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/202987459" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>Use this area to describe your project. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Est blanditiis dolorem culpa incidunt minus dignissimos deserunt repellat aperiam quasi sunt officia expedita beatae cupiditate, maiores repudiandae,
                nostrum, reiciendis facere nemo!</p>
              <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Date: Mid 2018</li>
                <li>Client: Austin Bonelli</li>
                <li>Category: 2D Animation</li>
              </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-primary-pink" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                Close Project
                              </button>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that resolved the issue of the video staying the same within the modal but now when the modal is closed, the video's audio continues to play..

Comment: I think I fixed it! I changed around my Javascript to have unique IDs that match the div modals rather than one id trying to target multiple classes, if that makes sense. In other words, each stop function has a unique ID for each model. 




Javascript

$('#modal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $('#modal1 iframe').attr("src", $("#modal1 iframe").attr("src"));
});

$('#modal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  $('#modal2 iframe').attr("src", $("#modal2 iframe").attr("src"));
});

...and so on for each added modal.

Comment: I updated the snippet with what you wrote, is that what you meant? I do see it working! let me know

Comment: Nah, I changed the Javascript ! it's working tho. i appreciate the help! i was dying..